# function prototypes in main function?

Tags: c, function, function-prototypes

As i understand we can not declare a function inside another function. But we can call one function in another function.

In main function we we usually call functions like this:

```
int abc(int some)
{
  return x;
}

int main()
{
  int x = 10;
  abc(x); //calling function abc inside main function.
  return 0;
}
```

but today while looking at a sample code i saw something like this:

```
int main()
{
  int abc(int x); // which compiled fine 
}
```

which works, but only thing I am trying to understand here is what is use of such statements?.

1. We can not define a function inside main function.
2. We can call functions inside main function.
3. but this one looks like more of a function prototype which is also declared outside all functions at the start of c program files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a matter of scope. You can declare the prototype of a function inside the main. The thing is that it will only be able to be called inside the main, and nowhere else. And the actual code of the function will be outside of the `main method`.

So in your second example, where `int abc(int x);` is *inside* the `main`, the function `abc` will only be able to be called inside the main function.

Answer (score 1):

The `int abc(int x);` declaration is indeed a function prototype. Although it is certainly true that we can not define a function inside main function, we can tell the compiler that a function exists inside another function, which is what a prototype does.

Although you certainly *can* declare a function inside a function, the utility of doing it that way is certainly limited: all external functions in C belong to a global namespace (although their visibility is limited to the scope enclosing the prototype declaration), so hiding a prototype inside a function is not commonly required.

Comment: They don't belong to a global namespace. Their scope is that of the enclosing block.

Comment: @mafso He means that the *function* itself has external linkage and does not have any sort of scope qualifying its definition.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I think dasblinkenlight didn't intend anything wrong, but I think the wording is misleading. To me, “namespace” actually means “scope” (when talking about C). AntonH's answer covers this better, I think (i.e. what the differences to a file scope declaration are).